# how to extract dynamically populated alphanumeric word from pipe delimited file

Tags: java

I am trying to print (Sys.out) alphanumeric word that is dynamically populated in piped delimited file. So far i am able to read the file and also iterate through each word by character but i want to print this word as whole instead of printing it as a word by word in a line.

Below is my attempted code -

```
public void extract_id() {

    File file= new File("src/test/resources/file.txt");
    Scanner sc=null;
    String str=null;
    try {
        sc=new Scanner(file);

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            str=sc.nextLine();
            parseID(str);

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sc.close();
}

private void parseId(String str) {
    String printId;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(str);
    sc.useDelimiter("|");

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        if(sc.next().contains("ID")){
            printId=sc.next();
            System.out.println("Id is "+printId);
        }       
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

My goal is to print - AF12345

Sample Delimited pipe file

```
id|1|session|26|zipCode|73112
id|2|session|27|recType|dummy
id|3|session|28|ID|AF12345|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the delimiter string you're passing to [`Scanner.useDelimiter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-). That method is expecting a *regular expression* and the pipe (`|`) character happens to be a reserved one in this context, which means that you need to escape it, i.e. call the method like this:

```
sc.useDelimiter("\\|");
```

However, you don't need to use another `Scanner` for parsing the Id from the line of text. [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) is enough:

```
private void parseId(String str) {
    String[] tokens = str.split("\\|");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (tokens[i].equals("ID")) {
            String idValue = tokens[i + 1]; // this will throw an error if
                                            // there is nothing after ID on
                                            // the row
            System.out.println("Id is " + idValue);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I am able to see Id value. Thnk you very much.

Comment: I edited the answer. Your original code should also work if you change the `sc.useDelimiter()` call slightly

Comment: Awesome thnk u for sharing ur idea